# How to fix my sub-class loops from only looping once when called in the main?

Tags: java, arrays, loops

When running the program (built and run in NetBeans 8.2) it will only run the sub-class loops once when it should be running through three times, once for each user inputted variable value.

I have attempted to adjust the m[0].length replacing it with: m.length, >4, >3, =>3, =>4, converted the for loops as NetBeans advised: for (double[] m1 : m).

```
public class ConversionRate {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //scanner for user input for variables
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //declare variables to be used
        String currency;
        double [][] m = new double[3][3];

        //user input for starting rate to be converted
        System.out.print("Enter USD or EURO as the starting currency to be " +
                "converted: ");        
        currency = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter " + m.length + " values to be converted, " + 
                "adding a space between each value: ");

        for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j == 0; j++){
                m[i][j] = input.nextDouble();
            }
        }
        if (currency.equalsIgnoreCase("USD")){
        for (int k = 0; k < m.length; k++){
            System.out.println("Converted Value        " + 
                "  Conversion Rate");
            System.out.println("=========================================");
            System.out.println("  " + convertedUs(m,k) +
                    "                      " + conversionRateUs(m,k));
        }
        }
        else if (currency.equalsIgnoreCase("Euro")){
        for (int k = 0; k < m.length; k++){
            System.out.println("Starting Value      Converted Value      " + 
                "  Conversion Rate");
            System.out.println("=========================================" + 
                "==================");
            System.out.println("                         " + convertedEuro(m,k) +
                    "                      " + conversionRateEuro(m,k));
                }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid selection, please try again.");
        }
    }
```

```
public static double conversionRateUs (double [][] m, int columnIndex){

        double conversionRateUs = 0.02; 
        double value2 = 0.00;

        for (int i = 0; i < m[0].length; i++){
            value2 = m[i][columnIndex] * (0.02 * 100) / 100;
        }      
            return value2;

}
```

```
public static double conversionRateEuro (double [][] m, int columnIndex){

        double conversionRateEuro = 0.08; 
        double value2 = 0.00;

        for (int i = 0; i < m[0].length; i++){
            value2 = m[i][columnIndex] * (0.08 * 100) / 100;
        }      
            return value2;
}
```

Expected results would calculate the total converted rate and the conversion "tax" rate to perform the charge for each value inputted by the user, it is currently only displaying the first value only.

Comment: since  " for (int j = 0; j == 0; j++){ " result as : m[i][0] = input.nextDouble(); m[i][1] and m[i][2] undefined

Comment: Blackout, are you trying to put the user's input in the first column of each row of the array? If so, what exactly do you expect to get out of the conversion functions? Is it supposed to convert each input into a new value and then return that value? If not, could you give some sample data of what you expect to see from each input?

Comment: Is it supposed to be something similar to this? https://gist.github.com/sometowngeek/0eaf0dcec5e7318f24f66347ef3748b1

Comment: Sometowngeek: I did attempt to make some changes to the initial loop in my code. It is working now t calculate the multiple loops and display them. the complication that I am experiencing now though is that it is asking for 9 different value inputs from the user prior to moving on. I only want my code to ask for 3 values then move on as the array will then be filled with the calculated outputs for conversion rate and the converted amount.

Comment: So... you want each row of the array to be like this `[original amount, converted amount, rate]`?

Comment: FYI, the best way to get my attention is to tag me with @ as if you were talking to me. Like this `@sometowngeek`

Comment: @sometowngeek thanks for the notice. I did figure out my problem, I was trying to utilize a multidimensional array when I only needed to use a single dimensional array. Working on the format of information now, but I got the calculations and output to finally work appropriately: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Blackout1392/ConversionCalculator/master/Calculator?token=AL7S45TWWC7ZXQZWUWATKYS4ZYH44

Answer (score 0):

I did figure out my problem, I was trying to utilize a multidimensional array when I only needed to use a single dimensional array. Working on the format of information now, but I got the calculations and output to finally work appropriately:

https://gist.github.com/sometowngeek/0eaf0dcec5e7318f24f66347ef3748b1